# Infinite loop. Java BigInteger

Tags: java, biginteger

I have the following "while" loop in my Java code. All the variables in my code are BigIntegers.

```
BigInteger d=new BigInteger("1");
BigInteger e=new BigInteger("3");
BigInteger phi1=new BigInteger("6336");
while(true)
{
    if(((d.multiply(e)).mod(phi1)).equals(BigInteger.ONE))
        break;
    d=d.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    //System.out.println(d);
}
```

The loop is getting executed infinitely in this case. But I want to add a break on the following condition:

```
if((d*e)%phi1==1)
    break;
```

which I have converted into BigInteger as

```
if(((d.multiply(e)).mod(phi1)).equals(BigInteger.ONE))
    break;
```

Where am I getting it wrong? Can anyone tell why the loop is executing infinitely?

Comment: When "sum of the digits % 3" is zero, then the number is a factor of 3. Since 6+3+3+6 = 18 % 3 is 0, then the number is factor of 3 → The condition will be never met.

Comment: Or you could just notice that each digit is a multiple of 3... :P 6336/3 = 2112

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`6336` is a multiple of `3`, hence the condition that you're attempting to `break` upon would never be true.

Infinite loop is inevitable.

Comment: I was calculating it :_(

Comment: plus: (((d.multiply(e)).mod(phi1)).equals(BigInteger.ONE)) is equal to d.multiply(e).mod(phi1).equals(BigInteger.ONE), you can refactor it so it'll be easier to read

Comment: @MarounMaroun From where do you get those → ?

Answer (score 0):

You are dividing 3*d by 6336, and checking the remainder r. Let k be the division result:

```
3d = k*6336 + r
=> r = 3*(d - 2112*k)
```

Which means that the remainder is always a multiple of 3, therefore it can never be 1.